# PlantUML State Machine control arrow direction to itself layout

Tags: plantuml

How do I draw an arrow out from the left side of the layout component?

When I using

```
@startuml
[*] --> A
A -right-> A
A -left-> A 
@enduml
```

[image]

but both arrows were drawing out from the right of the layout component A.

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: no, i use a workaround is put a diamond and use if else case to link it back

Comment: I'm having the issue as described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874550/plantuml-how-to-avoid-overlap-of-self-arrows-and-directional-and-select-side-of... would you have a solution for that? I'd like to have the arrow to self, but on the left-side of the object

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have arrows going left or right (edit: [see the forum request](https://forum.plantuml.net/2820/move-transition-arrow-to-self-in-state-diagram)). They are merely hints for layout (GraphViz does the work). Some things you can try:

- Label the transition (the arrows get spaced out):

```
@startuml
[*] --> A
A --> A :transition1
A --> A :transition2
A --> B : other
@enduml
```

[image]

- If you have more than one "self" transition, put them all on the same transition.

```
@startuml
[*] --> A
A --> A :transition1\ntransition2
A --> B : other
@enduml
```

[image]

Finally, try to use vertical (`-->`) as much as possible, since the GraphViz layout avoids overlapping if you can allow vertical edges. Sometimes the resulting graphs are bigger in size, but you don't have to goof around tweaking an algorithm you can't really control.

Comment: The question states: "How do I draw an arrow out from the left side of the layout component" but I see nothing of the kind in your answer.

Comment: The first line of my answer: "I don't think it's possible to have arrows going left or right." I didn't want to end it there ;-) so I tried to help you out with some suggestions.